# How can I make clusters with highly right skewed data?

Tags: clustering, group-differences, cluster-sample

My histogram of expected income is as below.

As you can see, income is highly right skewed. I want to divide individuals with regard to income - for example into Low, Middle, and High, and then I want to compare the other properties of individuals in each of the three groups.

Any idea about dividing into groups with highly right skewed data?

[image]

Comment: Take the logarithm of **x** and then plot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-linear function. Functions such as $\log x$, $e^x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ change skewedness of your data.

The exact "correct" scaling depends on your data, and can often only be guessed.

For income data, $\log(x)$ or $\log(x+1)$ might work.